# How to check what is Written in the url bar and navigate to a certain page in php?

Tags: php, url

What i want to be able to do is if someone writes in the url bar

www.somesite.com/test

test is like the Username name so it will be www.somesite.com/Username
then page navigate to another and display data from the data where the username is the same

The page will navigate to another page and display data from he database

is this possible first of?

And this is what i have write now it not much, and i am also new to PHP

```
$url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url2 = "http://www.somesite.com/"$databaseVar1=mysql_result($result,$i,"username");

if ($url) == ($url2)
{
header("location: http://somesite.com/viewcontent.php");
}
else
{
//not found
}
```

Am i Able to do something like this? Any help will be great-full thanks

Comment: You will have to configure your server too. What server are you using? Apache?

Comment: There are 2 errors in your code: should be `if($url)` not `if Url`. Also `header("Location: ` should be with a capital L

Comment: @Gerve "Also header("Location: should be with a capital L". Why? Says who?

Comment: @Gerve: HTTP header names are case-insensitive by definition. You can write it as `lOCatiON` if you like.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽: Sorry, my bad. It's not required by specification but it is convention.

Comment: I see you've edited the post, but you still have a mistake in your `if` statement. You're missing `$` and `()`

Comment: Hey thanks i made the changes.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP this is not exactly possible, however, you can do the following:

```
www.somesite.com/index.php/test
```

Apache will open index.php and you can use something like `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to navigate from there

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you could also set up Apache with mod_rewrite to redirect `/XX` to `/index.php/XX`.

Comment: Thanks @jadkik94. Good point. I think, however, that you have to do that for each possible value of XX manually and from the question, it seems to me like this would need to be dynamic as in the case of a Username

Comment: @neelsq You can also use regular expressions :)  (you would still need to check on the PHP side if what you get is a valid username though)

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to use a rewrite rule in .htaccess to redirect all requests to index.php. Index.php can then use

Or you can put a ? before the username. Then index.php will automatically get all requests. The $_SERVER['querystring'] will then receive the username.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the index.php as the application dispatcher and create an .htaccess file that will redirect the requests to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

index.php:

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //=> '/Users/show'

if ($page == '/some/page/') include('file_that_handles_this_request.php');
```

Or you could use this to create instances of classes and call methods:

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //=> '/Users/show'
list($class, $method) = explode($page);

$object = new $class();
$object->{$method}();
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken some assumptions (due to lack of complete source code in your question):

1. mysql connection is estabilished
2. proper query has been sent to mysql server
3. variable $i is set to meaningful value
4. www server is configured to rewrite requests to index.php

You only have to compare REQUEST_URI with "username" column value taken from database.
Header "Location: ..." must have capital letter "L".

And avoid usage of "==" operator when comparing strings in PHP, strcmp() function is more reliable - "==" operator tests identity not equality - it's useful to compare numeric values.

Comment: @CBroe is correct stating that HTTP headers are case insensitive, but apparently PHP is not - PHP will ignore lowercased header and/or emit warning :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use **mvc architecture** to get perfect as you want.
the url in mvc is like same as you want. You can call the **method** with the **parameter** from url directly. Here is a url pattern in **mvc architecture** -
*www.yoursitename.com/controller/methodname/parameter*